# Sails JS: How to prevent sails from changing database schema, while migrate:safe?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

As per the documentation, writing `migrate: safe` prevents auto migration of tables. I have written the same in **config/models.js**.

The issue is, every time I hit the API url, it changes the schema. That is if I change the field type from `string` to `text`, it reflects in the table. The main problem is, it removes the column level comments from the table. I am having columns having status stored in it. So I have placed informative comments in all these columns, which are removed every time.

I have searched if there is any attribute provided for retaining the comments, but couldn't found any solution.

I am new to Sails JS and I am using Sails JS v0.12 with MySql.

Comment: try defining migrate: safe at model level also

Comment: You mean in particular model file, e.g. Users.js?

Comment: I would double-check that you've configured `migrate: safe` properly in your `config/models.js` file.  It should definitely not be doing any modification to your tables.  And modification would only ever happen on `sails lift`, not after hitting an API endpoint.

Comment: @BCoder ye at particular model, where you define table name

Comment: @Arshad I have tried it. But the same issue.

Comment: @sgress454 Yes, that is what it should be. We have adjusted with column types and all, but column level informative comments are removed. I couldn't find any attribute to set comment in model.

Comment: check `config/env/development.js`, it might be taking the settings from there, try to set: `models: { migrate: 'safe' }` there